# Multiple conflicts after merging multiple repositories into one

Tags: git

I merged multiple repositories into one single repository by following this tutorial: https://leewc.com/articles/how-to-merge-multiple-git-repositories-into-one-repo/. But it seems it wasn't a good way because right now when I try to merge a feature into my branch test, I have 100 conflicts.

I created this feature in the new repository after the merging of all repositories into my new repository. The ancient repositories were `formation-front`, `formation-back` and `formation-services`, and I have now a single repository `formation` that contains the folders `formation-front`, `formation-back` and `formation-services`. The ancient repositories didn’t share file names or paths.

For example I had one repository `formation-front`, with 3 branches: `dev`, `test` and `master`. So I created a branch `project_A_dev` in the new repository, and I merged the branch `dev` of `formation-front` inside this branch. I did that for the 3 branches `dev`, `test` and `master` of my 3 repositories.

How does Git identify the files? Do the files have an id? Are the errors and the conflicts because of the fact that certain files have ancient id due to the old repo I was merging from, and certain files have new id? I didn't have all these conflicts before merging repositories.

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to make it more readable, and add the code/output you've used. If it's a software bug, [_try contacting the developers_](https://support.gitkraken.com/).

Comment: What are you trying to merge? Did you branch the feature branch off the already combined repository or off one of the separate repositories?

Comment: Without knowing more about what you're trying to do it's impossible to answer. Did you create the branch you're now trying to merge before or after you merged in all the unrelated repositories? Did those unrelated repositories share file names and paths, meaning that you did not just combine the histories, you also merged the files?

Comment: Also, why did you merge repositories like this at all?

Comment: Hello I edited my post in order to provide you more information.

Answer (score 1):

When you merged as described and have different branches for the different projects, a merge from one branch to another is not trivial since they have completely unrelated histories. You have to provide more detail about which branches currently exist in your repository, how they are different, and especially from which to which you're trying to merge.

The approach described in your link is a somewhat queer usage for branches. Branches are not intended to hold completely different projects, but different states of a single project.

Either your projects are so connected that it's justified to put them into a single repository side by side (but *not* on different branches) or they should live in separate repositories. In the first case, you can follow the instructions your linked article links to ([this one](http://julio.meroh.net/2014/02/how-to-merge-multiple-git-repositories.html)). This should result in a single master branch containing all your projects, without the merge issues you're currently having.

Disclaimer: Of course, it's up to you how to use git and it's features. There's no one-and-only way of using git. But using branches in the described way is very unusual and does not seem to be a good workflow.

Comment: Hello kowsky could you please explain me why the tutorial i linked is not a good workflow ? Also I edited my post in order to provide you more information.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you now have three branches for each of your three projects, so nine branches in total. That is unnecessary, since you already separate your projects by placing them in different folders. Why not combine the three 'dev' branches to a single branch?
It's  not a good workflow because branches are not intended to separate different projects, but rather to keep different versions of the same project.

Comment: Hello kowski thank you for your answer :) No i have right now 3 different branches : dev, test and master, not 9. All these projects are in fact the same project, before i had the back-end and the front-end separated but now they are together. Do you think that if I merge test into master, and dev into test, I will not have any merge conflicts anymore ? Do the id of the files in git exist ?

Comment: Git does not track files by any ids. It compares file content. From which branch did you branch the test branch off, and when? Did every repository have a `dev`, `test` and `master` branch? And you merged each other repositories `dev` into the main `dev`, and the same with `master` and `test`??

Comment: Yes every repo had dev, test and master branches. I had for example one front project with dev, test and master, one back project with dev, test and master, one service project with dev, test and master. I merged all these repo into one sigle repo with dev, test and master. All these repo are about one signle project.

Comment: Why is that I have all these conflicts when I try to merge my feature into dev ? And when I try to pen the files in conflict in Gitkraken I have an error. This is since to the merging all all repo into one sigle, in the new repo.

Comment: Well, if I get you right you merged two `dev` branches from different repositories. That is your new `dev` branch. You did the same with `test`. Then you started a feature branch from the new, merged `dev` and try to merge it to the new merged `test`. Correct?

Comment: If so, both of your branches have huge parts of unrelated history that needs to be merged. Just think of the last common successor of both branches and everything that has changed since then. That is why so many conflicts arise. I suspect there is no way around this if you merge your branches in this crude way. A better approach would be to merge both repositories in a single branch, e.g. merge `test` and `master` in `dev` in all repositories, just merge the `dev` branches, and branch fresh `master` and `test` branches off from there.

Comment: OK thank you :) But for the future if I merge dev into test, and test into master, this will merge the unrelated histories, and I will not have any merge conflicts furthermore ?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you want to merge `dev` into `test` in the future without having all these conflicts, you should merge `test` into `dev` once and resolve all conflicts. After that, there should be no more conflicts when merging from `dev` (or a branch  that branched off from it) to `test`.